# Align last item to left

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Google's official Flexbox implementation to align squares and I want to know if is possible to align last item to left. I tried to use app:justifyContent="flex_start" but it didn't fit all screen like app:justifyContent="space_between". I searched but found nothing about it. Can you help me? Here is the [image of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0rfy.png) and this is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:justifyContent="space_between"
            app:flexWrap="wrap"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

        </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is your dependency for FlexboxLayout?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'

Comment: It doesn't run with that dependency

Comment: so tell me in which dependency it runs O-O

Comment: Attach your full dependencies please